# improvement suggestions for parsing numpy array to single value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, aggregate, mask

I wrote a function to aggregate a 2D numpy integer n X m array to a 1 X 1 2D numpy array based a selected method. How can my function be improved to enhance speed/performance?

The methods are:

1. min: return the lowest value
2. max: return maximum value
3. median: return most frequently occurring value.
4. priority value: return specified `priority` value if its occurrence in the array exceeds a threshold `th`.

Additional requirements:

1. if the values in the input value are all identical, then return that number
2. an `ignore` value can be provided which is masked from the methods, but not the requirement above.

My current implementation:

```
import numpy as np

def array2val(arr, method, dt, prio=None, th=None, ignore=None):
    """
    Parse a Numpy array to a single output value based on method. Useful for aggregation
    :param arr: 2D numpy array
    :param method: [sum, min, max, median, priority]. priority means to give priority to a value if it occurs >= a threshold
    :param dt: datatype of output array
    :param prio: the value to be prioritized if method == priority
    :param th: occurrence treshold for the priority value. Return median if threshold is not exceeded
    :param ignore: value to ignore in all methods
    :return: 2D numpy array with shape (1,1) with value following above, unless the input array has all same values,
             then return that value. This trumps ignore values
    """

    # All values are the same, return this value
    if arr.std() == 0:
        return np.array([[arr[0, 0]]]).astype(dt)

    # Mask away ignored values if requested
    if ignore is not None:
        arr = np.ma.array(arr, mask=np.where(arr == ignore, True, False))
        v, c = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)
        vals = v.data[~v.mask]  # Values with ignore value removed
        counts = c[~v.mask]     # Counts with ignore value removed
    else:
        vals, counts = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)

    if method == 'median':
        out = vals[counts.argmax()]
        return np.array([[out]]).astype(dt)

    elif method == 'priority':
        if counts[np.where(vals == prio)] >= th:  # priority value is in the array and exceeds treshold
            return np.array([[prio]]).astype(dt)
        else:  # priority value does not exceed treshold or is not in the array at all.
            out = vals[counts.argmax()]  # default to most occuring value
            return np.array([[out]]).astype(dt)

    elif method == 'sum':
        return np.array([[arr.sum()]]).astype(dt)

    elif method == 'min':
        return np.array([[arr.min()]]).astype(dt)

    elif method == 'max':
        return np.array([[arr.max()]]).astype(dt)

    else:
        raise Exception('Invalid method for aggregation')
```

Comment: `np.array([[arr.sum()]])` can be replaced by `arr.sum(keepdims=True)`, same for `min` and `max`. What you call `median` should actually be called "mode", you can get it with [`scipy.stats.mode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html). I'm not sure I understand `priority`, but in any case you shouldn't call `np.unique` unless you really need it (e.g. you definitely not need it for `sum`, `min` or `max`).

Comment: This is the kind of "how do I improve working code' question that may be a better fit on CodeReview.  Answers there tend to focus more on function style and organization.  But they are pickier about it being a full working example.  SO is better for debugging, or specific performance issues such as "vectorizing" loops (numpy style).

Comment: Thanks! What would be a good code-review site?

Comment: @jdehesa, thanks for your suggestions. I've eliminated `np.unique` so that should help!

Comment: There is a [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: Make sure you read their [FAQ on asking questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915) before posting. Code Review expects a completely different kind of question than Stack Overflow does, but I think your question can be made to fit.